# Facebook Js API share method callback response empty

Tags: javascript, facebook, callback, share

i'm trying to use the Facebook share dialog with javascript api.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href:'http://thewebsiteurl.com'
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response);});
```

it works, i can share the website url, but the callback response gives me [], and nothing else.
I tried with my dev account, and my wife standard fb account, and still the same.
how can i check if everything went fine ? the idea was to give a bonus to the user sharing the url so i need to check if he really shared it.
is testing if response isn't undefined enough ?

thanks

Comment: _“the idea was to give a bonus to the user sharing the url ”_ – you are __not allowed__ to reward users for sharing – go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse) please. _“4.5: Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_

Comment: in fact, it's not "a real app", i created the facebok app just to use the js api for adding a sharing fonctionnality to the website. but maybe it's the same thing. If the user share the website , he win 1 more chance to win (it's a draw), it still doesn't work ?

Comment: That is still the same thing, and not allowed. There is no such distinction between “real” apps, and whatever you would call the opposite of those. You are using an app id, you are using the API – and therefor the terms laid out in Platform Policies apply.

Comment: ok i understand, but from what i read in your link, if you check the quesiton mark, there's an exemple that can be ok for Fb. Anyway, if we forgot this point, when i'm publishing the share or cancelling it, it returns [] for both, so i can't know if it's a success of a fail.

Comment: The first example in the picture behind the question mark is what is applicable here – you are not allowed to give the user _any_ benefits for sharing.

Comment: Ok i'll change that so, but i'd like to know why it returns me [] and there's no post_id or something like that. i can't know if the user shared or cancelled (can be usefull for tracking purposes also)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response

Comment: i read that. As you may notice, i'm french, and maybe i misunderstood this part. if i'm the user X,and i want to share the website , i click on the link, popup appears etc etc and i share. but (as User X is already looged in on fb) it's doesn't ask for autorisation or somethin like that, is it a User param ? can i do somehting specific for that ?

Comment: _“but (as User X is already looged in on fb) it's doesn't ask for autorisation or somethin like that”_ – it is not supposed to; being logged in to Facebook is enough to use the Share dialog, it doesn’t need any additional permissions or the user exposing any of their data to your app. If you want to get a response from the dialog, then you need to make the user login and grant your app permission first – but since is totally unnecessary to achieve the functionality, users will most likely not like that very much, so your actual number of shares might even drop.

Comment: And you would need to submit your app for review to Facebook, so that they approve your use of the permission, before you can ask users for it – and they will most likely _not_ approve it, telling you exactly what I just told you: That it is not necessary for sharing. So please, give it a rest – let users share simply using the dialog, without pestering them for additional, unnecessary permissions.

Comment: all i wanted is to understand why. So now i have your explanations it's ok, i don't want to ask people additionnal permissions, i don't need that, i was just trying to understand. Thanks or you answers